# Would there be a problem if I set 2 hostnames in my server?

Tags: hosts

Would there be a problem if I set 2 hostnames in my server?

```
vi /etc/hostname
```

```
dns01.hello.com
proxy01.hello.com
```

and in my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 dns01.hello.com
127.0.1.1 proxy01.hello.com
```

Cause I will run a proxy and bind service in this server. Kindly advise please.

Answer (score 0):

Better:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost dns01.hello.com proxy01.hello.com
```

All are on the same line.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that its possible to put on the same line..

Comment: I always have multiple hostnames. It's never been a problem for me.